# CakePHP Error: Call to a member function parseAccept() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have just upgraded from `CakePHP 1.3` to `cakePHP 2.4.5`.

I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal Error
Error: Call to a member function parseAccept() on a non-object  
File: /myapp/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/RequestHandlerComponent.php  
Line: 157
```

I'm not calling the function `parseAccept()` anywhere within my controller, and so don't understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### From the Cake Manual

> Controller’s constructor now takes two parameters. A CakeRequest, and
> CakeResponse objects. These objects are used to populate several
> deprecated properties and will be set to $request and $response inside
> the controller.

---

### The Fix:

Change your constructor signature..

**From:**

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

**To:**

```
// Pass through the request and response objects 
// AND declare the visibility of the method
public function __construct($request = null, $response = null)
{
    parent::__construct($request, $response);
}
```

This should resolve your `Error: Call to a member function parseAccept() on a non-object`    .

The official `Cake 2.x` docs for *this issue* can be found here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#controller

If you have just upgraded from `1.x` to `2.x`, I would highly recommend you read through the  detailed migration guides provided by `cakePHP`.

### Migration Guides

[2.0 Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html)
[2.1 Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html)
[2.2 Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-2-migration-guide.html)
[2.3 Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-3-migration-guide.html)
[2.4 Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-4-migration-guide.html)

Answer (score 3):

In Cakephp 2.x The AppController's __contruct() has two objects. CakeRequest and Cake Response. 
You need to pass to the parent contruct

```
   public function __construct($request = null, $response = null) {
        parent::__construct($request, $response);
           //you code here
    }
```